# CCSprite may not respond to "Method"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

### **EDIT**

Thank you all for the fast replying.

jtbandes comment made me find the problem.

musical_note_instance was being declared in the interface as CCSprite *musical_note_instance and note MusicalNote *musical_note_instance since its super was CCSprite the code was working, but warnings about semantic was being displayed. Now I fixed changing CCSprite to MusicalNote and no more warning are being shown.

*PS: I'm answering here because I'm a new user and can't answer my question in less them 8 hours.*

---

I'm new to cocoa and iPhone game programming, so I'm using cocos2d-iphone framework on my project.

Everything is going fine, but I'm having an issue that I can figure out why. I created this class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

@interface MusicalNote : CCSprite {

    NSString *note;
    NSString *soundFile;
    unsigned int noteValue;

}

+ (id) init;
+ (id) initWithFile:(NSString *)file;
+ (void) description;

- (void) playNote;


@property (nonatomic) unsigned int noteValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *note;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *soundFile;

@end
```

but when I try to do **[musical_note_instance playNote];**  or **[musical_note_instance setSoundFile:@"sound.mp3"];**  I get this warning in XCode **'CCSprite' may not responde to 'playNote'** I just can't figure out why =/

Comment: Where does `musical_note_instance` come from? You'll have to show some more code.

Comment: Could you post the code that is generating the warning? The place where you're invoking playNote on some object?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that some place you have a variable typed CCSprite that you'd like to now send your new playNote message too. But playNote only exists on instances of your new class MusicalNote. Have you changed the type of your variable to "MusicalNote *"?